# Docker не запускается

Tags: docker

Вот сам архив: [Архив](https://yadi.sk/d/UKs_5DbSz3M1Og)

Содержимое файла docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.14
        ports:
            - "${NGINX_HOST}:${NGINX_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html:cached
            - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        depends_on: [php]
        env_file: .env
        restart: always

    php:
        build:
            context: docker/php
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html:cached
            - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:cached
            - ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/99-custom.conf:cached
        user: "${DOCKER_UID}"
        env_file: .env
        restart: always
    db:
        image: "mysql:5.7"
        container_name: career_mysql
        volumes:
            - ./db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
               MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
               MYSQL_DATABASE: career_local
               MYSQL_USER: local
               MYSQL_PASSWORD: local
               VIRTUAL_HOST: mysql.career.test.local
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

Содержимое docker/php/Dockerfile:

```
    # See https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile
FROM php:7.1-fpm
ARG TIMEZONE

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    git \
    zlibc \
    zlib1g \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    unzip

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN mkdir /.composer/ && chmod 777 /.composer/

# Set timezone
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && echo ${TIMEZONE} > /etc/timezone
RUN printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', ${TIMEZONE} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini
RUN "date"

# Type docker-php-ext-install to see available extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql gd

# Install memcached extension
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2 build-essential libmemcached-dev libz-dev \
  && pecl install memcached \
  && echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini \
  && apt-get remove -y build-essential libmemcached-dev libz-dev \
  && apt-get autoremove -y \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /tmp/pear

RUN docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends default-libmysqlclient-dev

RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Содержимое файла docker/nginx:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log off;
    error_log /dev/null crit;
    client_max_body_size 1024M;
    client_header_buffer_size 4k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https {
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        root   /var/www/html;
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;

        access_log off;
        error_log /dev/null crit;
        charset utf-8;

        location ~ ^/(\.git|log|docker|\.env) {
            return 404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 7200;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 72000;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https if_not_empty;
            fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_forwarded_for;
            include        fastcgi_params;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite  ^(.*)/index.php$  $1/ redirect;
            }
        }

        location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php last;
            }
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(xml|html|jpg|jpeg|gif|ttf|eot|swf|svg|png|ico|mp3|css|woff2?|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|dat|avi|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|wmv|mpeg|mpg|mp4|m4a|spx|ogx|ogv|oga|webm|weba|ogg|tbz|js)$ {
            expires 30d;
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

В консоли пишу команду docker-compose up --build
Получаю вот такую ошибку:

> for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint career_nginx_1 (cfb585f2e85e040b3dac6c5a625a272533d1a9b824e5a9d43cc37571bb308ed2): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
> Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Помогите кто знает. Использую Docker Desktop. Операционная система Win10

Comment: Сделайте docker ps

Comment: Сделал:  https://yadi.sk/i/garQbqCxyEafYg

Comment: Опубликуйте ответ, а не ссылку на ya.disk. Ссылка может протухнуть

Comment: rror starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Comment: Ок, завтра гляну. Я думал, что Вы решили проблему. Прицепите, пожалуйста, текст к вопросу

Comment: Так это не ответ, мне просто выложить куда то надо было.

Comment: Мне просто нужен рабочий проект, который можно было бы максимально просто и быстро развернуть у себя локально, и чтоб с БД тоже можно было бы работать. Сколько мануалы не читаю - пока понятного мало там.

Comment: Ты уверен что так можно? 
ports:
            - "${NGINX_HOST}:${NGINX_PORT}:80"
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Я уверен, что так нельзя... один порт прокиньте..